# Rails 5: Unpermitted parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I am trying to save nested models with cocoon gem. Here is the params json:

```
Parameters: {
  "utf8" => "✓",
  "authenticity_token" => "w/hwSu6yvT/R+6KFdoi7L6v3tDYJppiXyvQigBfTpD6EuTVz9P2CKImybxgip90YA0Yo7QKpID+IeCi2KLsy0g==",
  "project" => {
    "client" => "1", "name" => "Project 1", "instances_attributes" => {
      "1508163439344" => {
        "instances" => {
          "user_id" => "user1", "password" => "[FILTERED]", "service_url" => "http://localhost:3001"
        }
      }, "1508163446859" => {
        "instances" => {
          "user_id" => "user2", "password" => "[FILTERED]", "service_url" => "http://localhost:3002"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "commit" => "Create Project"
}
```

For strong parameters code in the project's controller:

```
def project_params
  params
  .require(:project)
  .permit(
    :client, :name,
    instances_attributes: Instance.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:_destroy)
  )
end
```

Now when I try to save it is showing me: `Unpermitted parameter: instances`

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried instance_attributes, on singular? Also I think you have to pass :id attribute to the list for cocoon, but I'm not sure

Comment: :id is getting handled by `Instance.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym)`

Comment: @RajMishra check my solution.It should work for u

Comment: Actually the issue was in model with proc for `reject_if`..

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 solutions :

- permit all the `instances_attributes` content :

  ```
  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:client, :name).permit!(:instances_attributes)
  end
  ```
- permit all the `instances_attributes` key :

  ```
  def project_params
    instances_keys = (params[:project] || {})[:instances_attributes].keys
    params.require(:project).permit(:client, :name, instances_attributes: instances_keys)
  end
  ```

Comment: It still `Unpermitted parameter: instances`

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice your params.Inside `instances_attributes` you have again nested hash called *`instances`. So you need to permit them as well. 
Update your `project_params` as below

```
def project_params
  params
  .require(:project)
  .permit(
    :client, :name,
    instances_attributes: [:instances=> Instance.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:_destroy)]
  )
end
```

Comment: instances_attributes is not an array. This won't work.

Comment: @AntoineDewaele Check in console. Its tested